# Numpy Discrete Fourier Transform (fft) on multiple arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is a follow-up question to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76081149/polyfit-for-a-seasonality-model)

I have several quite large pandas dataframes and I need to apply Numpy's fft function to denoise each row separately.

What I'm doing right now is iter through the rows of the dataframe and apply numpy fft on each row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10000, 52), columns=range(1,53))

output = np.empty((0,52))

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    spectrum = np.fft.rfft(row)
    spectrum[6:] = 0
    verified =np.fft.irfft(spectrum)
    output = np.vstack((output, verified))
```

This is the output:

```
            0         1         2         3         4         5         6   \
0     0.476861  0.449378  0.445224  0.458605  0.480861  0.504024  0.523671   
1     0.569499  0.642474  0.691314  0.703127  0.673323  0.607825  0.522125   
2     0.229334  0.206852  0.194395  0.186826  0.181918  0.181320  0.189769   
3     0.542612  0.485116  0.454579  0.454857  0.480331  0.517998  0.551836   
4     0.350204  0.428149  0.532144  0.627614  0.683061  0.680347  0.620361   
...        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...   
9995  0.241540  0.247316  0.296193  0.381337  0.487676  0.595264  0.683786   
9996  0.433201  0.386454  0.346898  0.324144  0.324614  0.349595  0.394791   
9997  0.585794  0.503882  0.450025  0.438172  0.469075  0.529971  0.598605   
9998  0.364178  0.363996  0.400953  0.465722  0.540743  0.605164  0.640928   
9999  0.720946  0.693376  0.642622  0.577479  0.510498  0.454305  0.418147   

            7         8         9   ...        42        43        44  \
0     0.540032  0.557019  0.579607  ...  0.482889  0.561783  0.642733   
1     0.437323  0.374242  0.347437  ...  0.294238  0.296055  0.301317   
2     0.212893  0.254505  0.314413  ...  0.484699  0.568643  0.623170   
3     0.567988  0.559083  0.526314  ...  0.490357  0.514340  0.561120   
4     0.522275  0.416836  0.336087  ...  0.326105  0.452154  0.574466   
...        ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...   
9995  0.737062  0.746413  0.712124  ...  0.364438  0.427846  0.487851   
9996  0.451591  0.509691  0.560211  ...  0.432432  0.453183  0.472881   
9997  0.650264  0.665516  0.636145  ...  0.545284  0.532642  0.546533   
9998  0.638102  0.597791  0.531701  ...  0.548747  0.573257  0.603792   
9999  0.405732  0.414925  0.439214  ...  0.765117  0.746037  0.711731   

            45        46        47        48        49        50        51  
0     0.709887  0.749437  0.753514  0.722475  0.664799  0.594611  0.527631  
1     0.305615  0.308494  0.314105  0.329759  0.362792  0.416867  0.489137  
2     0.638698  0.614139  0.556706  0.479495  0.397632  0.324239  0.267452  
3     0.622705  0.685017  0.731861  0.749860  0.732776  0.683743  0.614625  
4     0.658297  0.680878  0.638835  0.549281  0.444148  0.359660  0.324439  
...        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...  
9995  0.531525  0.548069  0.531840  0.484457  0.415239  0.339668  0.276112  
9996  0.491950  0.509969  0.524766  0.532484  0.528706  0.510272  0.477096  
9997  0.589529  0.652623  0.717826  0.764054  0.774347  0.741951  0.673153  
9998  0.630760  0.642783  0.630788  0.591811  0.531082  0.461475  0.400280  
9999  0.674761  0.647708  0.639035  0.650343  0.675875  0.704429  0.722997
```

On my PC this script takes 5-6 seconds. Considering I have hundreds of dataframes to run the script on, the whole process would take a lot of time.
Is there a way to apply the fft function on the whole dataframe, or anyway to make the script faster?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `output = np.vstack((output, verified))`, you should append each `verified` array that you create to a Python list, and then outside the loop, convert that list of arrays to a single array.  The way it is now, you *copy* the ever-growing `output` array each time the loop runs.  That makes your algorithm O(n²), where n is the length of the input DataFrame.

Comment: Instead of the loop, consider converting the input DataFrame to a numpy array, and use the `axis` parameter of `numpy.fft.rfft`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Warren Weckesser's comment, I found the following solution:

```
spectrum= pd.DataFrame(np.fft.rfft(df.to_numpy(), axis=1))
spectrum.iloc[: , 6:] = 0
output= pd.DataFrame(np.fft.irfft(spectrum.to_numpy(), axis=1))
```

There must be better solutions to avoid the back and forth from numpy to pandas, but it's 65,000 times faster than iterrows so that's fine for me :)

Comment: You should be able to do the equivalent of the `iloc` directly on the array produced by `rfft`.  Arrays don't have `iloc` but the indexing is just as powerful.